# Best way to use asyn/await in the following code

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, callback

I am kind of new in Javascript and I want to connect to DB and run a script. Then get the result of script and run functions in order.
If there is any error with one of the functions, it should stop and doesnt run other functions.

I tried the following:

```js
const {
  Client
} = require('pg')
const client = new Client({
  'connection info'
})

client.connect()
  .then(() => console.log('DB connected'))
  .catch(err => console.error('connection error', err.stack))

let dbResult

const data = async() => {
  try {
    dbResult = await client.query('SCRIPT') // array of json 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

const func1 = async() => {
  try {
    // do something with dbResult
    console.log('func1 success msg')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error in func1')
  }
}

const func2 = async() => {
  try {
    // do something with dbResult
    console.log('func2 success msg')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error in func2')
  }
}

const func3 = async() => {
    dbResult.forEach(result => {
    // do something
})
  try {
    // do something with dbResult
    console.log('func3 success msg')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error in func3')
  }
}

data()
func1()
func2()
func3()
```

Comment: Does this code work as is? Or are you seeing any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the functions you call are `async`, therefore return Promises and should be awaited. You can await all of them in a try/catch block, so if one fails, the others won't execute.

Don't use try/catch in each individual function, but rather here :

```
const data = async() => client.query('SCRIPT') // array of json 

const func1 = async() => console.log('func1 success msg')

const func2 = async() => console.log('func2 success msg')

const func3 = async() =>  dbResult.forEach(result => console.log(result))

(async () => {
    try{
        await client.connect();
        let dbResult = await data();
        dbResult = await func1(dbResult);
        await func2();
        await func3(dbResult);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
})();
```

`await Promise.all([data, func1, func2, func3])` would also fail if one of the Promises failed, but does not guarantee the execution order.

Comment: Will I be able to get error of each function? Lets say function 1 has error. I think try/catch would have been better in my opinion. Can u give me a reason why not use it?

Comment: But I did use try/catch. If any function throws an error, it will be caught in the one `catch(err)`.

Comment: Yes thats a good way. But how about getting the result of first function data() and use its result in other functions?

Comment: I did not understand (async () => {})() function :) first time i see. So this works as if its called somewhere? And why u give parameter in each function?

Comment: Ah, that's a self-executing anonymous function. `await` must be used inside an `async` function (except in very recent versions of Node where `await` can be directly used at top-level ("top-level await")

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy. One more question: from here [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#async%20function) I get that u can use an async function (a promise) by only calling it witout await. In the link example asyncCall() is a promise function but called only by asyncCall() without await

Comment: this means that my data function is also async and I can call it data() without await?

Comment: Of course you can call an `async` function without awaiting it. It will return a pending Promise, that's it. You can do `const myCall = myFunc(); const result = await myCall;` but it's easier to write `const result = await myFunc()`.

Comment: I dont get the client connection error when there is problem with DB connection. Without giving me the error of connection, it tries to run functions.

Comment: You should `await client.connect();` first, then. Currently, you are using a `.then()` callback, which allows `await data()` to run first (that is, before the DB connection is established)

Comment: can u please update the answer if possible. I think pg client has no async/await option

Comment: Answer updated. If you can write `something().then()`, it means that `something()` returns a Promise. Which means you can `await` it instead of pulling your hair out with the old `.then()` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Below is if you must use try catch inside each of your function body. If not, then I'd stick with the answer from Jeremy above.

What you can do is instead of console logging your errors that you receive in try..catch block, you can [throw new error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw), which will stop the execution of your code and console log the actual error.
(Well, not exactly console log, but rather console.error() it)

This will prevent the execution of other functions, unless you do something with your error (make some error handling where you can execute another code, depending on the error).

In general, the syntax for this as follows:

```
try {
  await someStuff();
} catch (err) {
  throw new Error(err)
}
```

Object `err` has some additional properties, such as `name` and `message`.
Here is more about [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) object.